# What "little guys" is Spider-Man referring to?

Tags: marvel, spider-man-into-the-spider-verse

In *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse* (2018) (Alt-Universe Cut), Ganke and Miles steal the Spider-Man movie and watch it. In a scene where Spider-Man's finger got stuck to a gear rod of a Maserati:

> Gluck: So how did you get your hand off the gearshift of your Maserati?
>
> Spider-Man: I don't drive a Maserati. I just had to learn to relax. You gotta get those **little guys** in your fingers to chill out. In through your nose...out through...
>
> Gluck: The mouth!

What little guys is Spider-Man referring to?

Comment: I presume he means the spikes on his fingers; https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJTDT.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you saw the first *Spider-Man* movie that came out in 2002 which starred Tobey Maguire, you might remember the scene where Peter Parker looks at his fingers and sees tiny barbs coming out of the tips. From then on, he could climb walls. In real life, spiders stick to walls with dense clusters of microscopic hairs at the end of their legs known as "scopulae." The hairs stick to objects. That's what Spider-Man was talking about in this context.